# Proper way to log circular referenced object when testing with karma?

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Suppose `obj` is an object with circular structure. `console.log(JSON.stringfy(obj,null,4))` throw cicular structure object error, meanwhile, `console.log(obj)` can cause unreadable output in console and `[object object]` output in broswer(chorme).

Is there a recommended way to console.log() complex object with the circular structure.

Comment: You can override the toString on the object.

Comment: Is there any util library to format object nicely logging in the console?